# Generated blob doesn't contain full dataset

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket, binary, blob

I'm trying to piece together a binary package (combination of strings, ints, & a file) in JavaScript that's then passed to a C# WebSocket server, but am unable to get the entire dataset to be included in the blob. What I'm seeing is that the final output blob is much smaller than the sum of it's parts.

for example, the data file is 8890 unto itself, but finalBlob.size is only 119.

Ultimately I just need a small concise binary package that's assembled in Javascript of mixed data that I can run through a C# memory stream without having to have everything converted to UTF8 text.

```
fetch(request).then(data => AssemblePackage(data)).catch(error => {
    console.error("Unable to retrieve asset: " + error);
});
    
async function AssemblePackage(data){
    //Example Data
    var token = "3F73B3E6-7351-416F-ACA3-AE639A3F587F";
    var requestKey = 3;
    var requestId = "6BFF91D6-4346-424C-AE01-62E5C7F3C9BC";
    var assetName = "MyAssetFile.dat";
    
    let parts = [];
    //36 UTF8 chars (Includes guid '-' chars)
    parts.push(token);

    //2 UTF8 bytes max '00'-'99' (workaround for blob not storing an int as 
    //an int but a UTF8 string...)
    let chars = requestKey.toString().split('');
    while(chars.length < 2){
        chars.unshift('0');
    }
    parts.push(chars.join(''));

    //36 UTF8 chars (Includes guid '-' chars)
    parts.push(requestId);

    //3 UTF8 bytes max '000'-'999' (workaround for blob not storing an int as 
    //an int but a UTF8 string...)
    chars = assetName.length.toString().split('');
    while(chars.length < 3){
        chars.unshift('0');
    }
    parts.push(chars.join(''));

    //1-999 character string
    parts.push(assetName);

    //
    let fileBlob = await data.blob();

    parts.push(await this.ReadFileBlobAsUint8(fileBlob));

    var finalBlob = new Blob([parts], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
}

ReadFileBlobAsUint8(fileBlob){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        let rdr = new FileReader();

        rdr.onerror = () => {
            rdr.abort();
            reject(rdr.error);
        };

        rdr.onload = () =>{
            resolve(new Uint8Array(rdr.result));
        };
        rdr.readAsArrayBuffer(fileBlob);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up needing to do. It's not elegant, but it worked to resolve the issue.

The fetch request.

```
fetch(request).then(data => AssemblePackage(data)).catch(error => {
    console.error("Unable to retrieve asset: " + error);
});
```

Assemble the data

```
async AssemblePackage(data){
    var token = "3F73B3E6-7351-416F-ACA3-AE639A3F587F";
    var requestKey = 3;
    var requestId = "6BFF91D6-4346-424C-AE01-62E5C7F3C9BC";
    var assetName = "MyAssetFile.dat";
    
    if(data.ok){
        let textEnc = new TextEncoder();

        //36 char UTF8 GUID (Includes guid '-' chars)
        let rawToken = textEnc.encode(token);

        //single uint representing request Key
        let rawKey = new Uint8Array(1);
        rawKey[0] = requestKey;

        //36 char UTF8 GUID (Includes guid '-' chars)
        let rawId = textEnc.encode(requestId);

        //UTF8 string representing asset name max-length: 255 
        let rawName = textEnc.encode(assetName);

        //Single uint representing the length of the assetName
        let nameSize = new Uint8Array(1);
        nameSize[0] = rawName.byteLength;

        //byte[] representing the fetched asset
        let asset = new Uint8Array(await data.arrayBuffer());
             
           
        //Calculate combined size
        let size = rawToken.byteLength + rawKey.byteLength + rawId.byteLength;
        size += nameSize.byteLength + rawName.byteLength + asset.byteLength;

        //Alloclate new buffer
        let result = new Uint8Array(size);

        // Build the new array
        let offset = 0;

        result.set(rawToken, offset);
        offset += rawToken.byteLength;

        result.set(rawKey, offset);
        offset += rawKey.byteLength;

        result.set(rawId, offset);
        offset += rawId.byteLength;

        result.set(nameSize, offset);
        offset += nameSize.byteLength;

        result.set(rawName, offset);
        offset += rawName.byteLength;

        result.set(asset, offset);
        offset += asset.byteLength;

        //Do something with your byte[]
        SendData(result.buffer);

    }else{
        //Text Message
        console.error("Asset fetch failed: "+ data);
    }
}
```